# Inventory management - write off due to expiry qn

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, inventory

I have a list of items, expiry date, quantity, and usage. Goal is to find out how much of each item of each expiry date, if any, will need to be written-off as unused before expiring.

Different items may have different number of expiry dates. Assumption is that the shortest expiry dates stocks are used first (EEFO) [so different lines of the same item are linked], and that when stock expires, it cannot be used anymore.

I am assuming a VBA loop macro somehow is the best method. I was reading up and thought that maybe an array would be necessary too but I am a complete newbie at this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need VBA for this. You could do this with Excel formulae and it'd be really easy with some helper columns. If you don't want to show the helper columns you could put them on a 2nd hidden sheet and then just show the result on the display sheet. Any VBA you write would essentially do the same thing but with looping etc. might get a bit complicated if you're new to it.

To get these results:

[image]

I used these formulae:

[image]

I took your figures for item "E" but made up my own for item "D" so I could test changing the item in column A to make sure it worked.

Like I said in a comment, make sure that your expiry dates **per item** are sorted ascending.

(e.g. sort on expiry date, then items to get this table to work)

Another word of advice, if this stuff is happening on a grand scale then a SQL database would be good, if you have MS ACCESS you could try putting the data in there and re-asking the question.

Comment: Thanks jamheadart! The wrapping formula is what gets to me though. When there are different number of expiry dates per item [in my data it is anywhere between 1-13], the wrapping formula keeps changing and I cannot only refer to a fixed number of lines above it as the sum formula keeps changing too. Hence i thought it can't be done by formulae alone.

Comment: I would think as long as your expiry dates are in order in the table and you always use the lowest first, then the formula could be the same all the way down the chart (The example I have in the question is actually the wrong way round so would be problematic - I had changed the dates several times to check it was working and left it by mistake)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the wrapping formula

Comment: @jamheadart It looks from your results like none of item D with expiry date of 10/3/2021 will be used because qty left is the same as qty, why is this ? I would have thought some would be used in the 99 days between the expiry of the first batch on 1/12/2020 and its expiry on 10/3/2021.

Comment: Yeah I missed a bit, sorry I don't have the time to fully incorporate every aspect but it's completely achievable in formulae alone.